# How do I add labels dynamically using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I do not know how to use jQuery at all and I really need some help. Here is what
I'm trying to do...
[image: an example]

I need to add those labels next to those without any hard-coding the text in the HTML. I'm very
new to jQuery and would really love some help.

HTML

[image: first half of html]
[image: second pic of html]
[image: last pic of html]

jQuery (This is from a tutorial)

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
 $("body").append("<p>JSQuery Hello World");
 });



window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(evt) {
var elem = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var para = document.createElement("p");
var text = document.createTextNode("This is regular JS");
para.appendChild(text);
elem.appendChild(para);
});
```

Comment: Why use `getElementsByTagName` when you're using jQuery?

Comment: I was following a tutorial. I'm not sure what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution code**

```
<script src="your jquery src"></script>
<ul id="productList">
    <li data-type="family">Coffee</li>
    <li data-type="child">Tea</li>
    <li data-type="family">Milk</li>
    <li data-type="child">Milk</li>
    <li data-type="family">Milk</li>
</ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var listItems = $("#productList li");
        listItems.each(function (idx, li) {
            var product = $(li);
            product.append(" - <b> ("+product.attr('data-type')+") </b>");
            // and the rest of your code
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Explanation & logic:**

1. Identify `li`  in `#productlist` and store it in listItems
2. Loop through every listItems element via each loop
3. In DOM element here called `product`, append the value of data property using jquery `append()` function

> Please note: if no data attribute is defined, undefined will be
> printed instead of value. To resolve this bug you can add an if
> condition in each loop and then append.